# Which variation estimate to prefer: SD, geomSD, CV?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, coefficient-of-variation, geometric-distribution, geometric-mean

I have a case where we see regional disparities in median received services. *Services* is a **lognormally** distributed variable. Plot is based on a **lognormal model**, examining y and sigma.

You can see that some regions have a much higher variation of received services than others. Thus, we would like to show that these services are differently divided between the residents of different regions, using a variation estimate. Which of the variation estimates suits best for describing the fairness of service dividing?

**What do I mean with the fairness of service dividing?** Residents from different regions should receive an equal amount of services in terms of the median (a measure of central tendency). If medians are equal, there are no regional disparities in received services. However, resident-level disparities are also possible, meaning that medians may be equal between the regions but variations differ! The differing variations indicate that available resources, services, are divided with varying fairness. E.g. region A shows small variation, meaning that all residents receive relatively similar amount of services. In contrast, region B has high variation, meaning that some residents receive many services and some very few (a lot of extreme values = high variation).

**Should I prefer SD, GeomSD or Coefficient of Variation (CV)?**

[image]

Comment: If you could articulate what you mean by "fairness of service dividing," that could help settle the issue.

Comment: Good point! I added a new paragraph to the initial post.